# Problem with Npgsql Prepare

Tags: c#, npgsql

I'm trying to insert a row into a PostgreSQL through an application with C#. Following the steps showed in [Npgsql project homepage](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html), I tryied to build a prepared statement in order yo insert a row in the table. I got this:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = dbConn.getConnection();
conn.Open();
NpgsqlCommand query = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into table(c1, c2) values(:v1, :v2)", conn);
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("v1", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
query.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("v2", NpgsqlDbType.Text));
query.Prepare();
query.Parameters[0].Value = "something";
query.Parameters[1].Value = "else";
```

And got this error:

```
ERROR: 42601: syntax error in or near «:»
```

Any opinion?

thanks in advance

Comment: Uhu, why do you have the : there at all? just remove them. Might need to do it @v1,@v2 aswell (both in query and parameter), dunno about that connector.

Comment: It's just like the examples shows. I´ll try, Thanks

Comment: Would you mind to give it a try with the latest Npgsql release? Please let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure I will, I'll get you noticed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is from my working app so I know it works, if it does not let me know.

```
conn.Open();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("DELETE from accounts where user_name = :value1", conn);

// Now add the parameter to the parameter collection of the command specifying its type.
command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("value1", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));

//Now, add a value to it and later execute the command as usual.                
command.Parameters[0].Value = email;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Comment: I just realized you want a prepare. but the example may still be useful to you